# why the value of (n) in big oh notation examples is different?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis

can any one explain why the value of (n) in example 4.10 is greater than or equal to two while in example 4.11 is greater than or equal to one ( note that the term n log n is Existing in both examples ! )

example 4.10 :

```
5n^2 + 3nlogn + 2n + 5 is O(n^2)
```

Justification : `5n^2 + 3nlogn + 2n + 5 <= (5+3+2+5)n^2 = cn^2 , for c=15 , when n greater than or equal to 2  (note that n log n is zero for n = 1 ).`

example 4.11 :

```
20n^3 + 10nlogn  + 5 is O(n^3)
```

Justification : `20n^3 + 10nlogn  + 5 <= 35n^3  , for n greater than or equal to 1  .`

Comment: @MarcB  less than or equal to ...  Is it clear or not??

Comment: I see what you're saying. It may be an error in the book. Ask a professor or find a list of errata for the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function `f(n)` is called to be `O(g(n))` iff there exist such constant `C` and such `n0` that `f(n) <= C*g(n)` for all `n>=n0`.

This definition does not require any particular value of `n0`. So in your first example `n0=2`, in your second example `n0=1`, but the particular value does not matter for the big-O definition, it only needs that *some* (any) such `n0` exists.

(However, the value matters for proof, and this is why the value are different.)

Note also that `C` constants are also different: `C=15` in first example and `C=35` in second.

Comment: if in first example `n0 >=1` it is a correct in the proof ??

Comment: @safana, strange indeed. If you have not misprints in your question, then this may be a misprint in a book.